# Twig escaping html in if shorthand?

Tags: html, twig

I have a piece of template as follows:

```
<div class="reply_text"><div class="wall_reply_text">
    {{ reply.comment_text is empty ? '<div class="has-text-grey-light">This comment is empty.</div>' : reply.comment_text }}
</div></div>
```

Instead of showing `This comment is empty.` using the class `has-text-grey-light`, it shows literally this unescaped text: `<div class="has-text-grey-light">This comment is  empty.</div>`.

I believe that previously I already made similar things and it did output correctly. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ['raw'](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/raw.html) filter.

```
{{ var|raw }} {# var won't be escaped #}
{{ (true ? '<b>Hello 1</b>' : '<p>Hello 2</p>')|raw }}
```

The raw filter marks the value as being "safe", which means that in an environment with automatic escaping enabled this variable will not be escaped if raw is the last filter applied to it:

```
<div class="reply_text">
    <div class="wall_reply_text">
        {{ (reply.comment_text is empty ? '<div class="has-text-grey-light">This comment is empty.</div>' : reply.comment_text) | raw }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Another way is using if else statement where you don't need to use the raw filter.

```
{% if reply.comment_text is empty %}
    <div class="has-text-grey-light">This comment is empty.</div>
{% else %}
    {{ reply.comment_text }} {# if required {{ reply.comment_text | raw }} #}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. But I can swear I already did this without raw and it worked. What could be the reason?

Comment: Can't tell unless I see the code but you can do if you use if else statement. [like this](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/if.html)

Comment: I remember! I made the same shorthand, but for conditionally choosing the class inside the div tag, the tag wasn't inside the condition. But I see now, so you can't do this inside shorthands.